# Does fsync guarantee that a subsequent read is from the disk and not from a kernel buffer

Tags: linux, fsync

The linux `fsync` system call guarantees that when it returns any dirty kernel buffers have been flushed to the disk. I've seen a previous discussion about whether the data has necessarily actually been successfully written to the disk, but that isn't my question. I want to know whether the the kernel buffers have been freed, so that a subsequent read will get data from the disk and not from a kernel buffer.

In the absence of `fsync`, a kernel could keep the data until it needs the memory for some reason, and satisfy a subsequent read without actually reading from the disk: modern kernels do seem to do this. What I want to know is whether `fsync` prevents this: the man page doesn't say anything about it.

The behaviour matters if I'm testing a disk for write failures. If the data was not written correctly, I can only discover this by actually reading from the disk.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547061/writing-and-reading-the-same-fd-without-fsync-in-linux)?

Comment: Disk hardware may have its own cache, unrelated to any buffers kept by the OS

Comment: @harshavmb That is completely unrelated to what he is asking, other than containing the word "fsync"...

Comment: @smheidrich I don't think you read the link I posted otherwise you wouldn't have made this comment. `fsync` doesn't guarantee the read consistency it's from the OS buffer caches & that's what the above link I shared says. Reading helps!

Comment: @harshavmb Sorry, I read the question you linked, which is in fact about a separate issue, but you're right that its accepted answer strongly implies an answer to this question.

Comment: @smheidrich All I am saying is `fsync` does a different job of flushing buffers to disk. Doesn't that answer this question that `fsync` does a different job? To read from disk only `O_DSYNC` flag would do the job.

Comment: @harshavmb I actually take it back, there is nothing in the answers to the question you linked that implies an answer to this one (I misread the accepted answer). And I don't get what you're saying in this comment either. `O_DSYNC`, as far as I understand it, is equivalent to doing an `fsync` after every `write`. What is the connection to this question, which is about what happens when one `read`s after an `fsync`?

Comment: O_DIRECT might be relevant here, but I can't get it to work. With O_DIRECT set on the open(), I get EINVAL when I try to do a read which works without O_DIRECT set on the open(). I read the blocksize, close the fd, and open it again with O_DIRECT, so I know the blocksize is correct..

Comment: @RedComet in [this] says that fsync() followed by close() followed by open() followed by read() should get the data from the disk. I'll try it and see.[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547061/writing-and-reading-the-same-fd-without-fsync-in-linux

Comment: wrtite() followed by fsync() followed by close() followed by open() followed by read() does read back different data from what I wrote, so my SSD is defective. The test program is at https://github.com/rparkins999/DiskUtilities